# Is it possible to detect if BinaryReader.ReadBytes(int) reaches the end of a stream?

Tags: c#, io, binaryreader

Most of `BinaryReader`'s read methods throw an `EndOfStreamException` if it reaches the end of a stream, but strangely the `ReadBytes` method doesn't. But what if I do still want to throw an `EndOfStreamException`? How do I detect that?

I could use the `BaseStream.Position` property, but the steam I'm using does not support seeking, so this would throw a `NotSupportedException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while typing my question. It turns out that, if the end of the stream is reached, the method simply returns a shorter array. So this is how you can detect it:

```cs
byte[] bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes(someNumber);
if (bytes.Length != someNumber)
    throw new EndOfStreamException(); // Or do something else.
```